# How to get the size of @Param in @Query Repositories JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, jpql

I have a question and it is that I want to know the size of a **@Param** that I pass to the **@Query** but it gives me the following error when compiling:

```
unexpected token: : near line 1
```

I show you the code of my query:

```
  @Query(
  value = "SELECT DISTINCT company "
      + " FROM Company company "
      + " left join  company.companyProducts products "
      + " inner join  empresa.servicios services "
      + "   WHERE services.idService IN (:idsServices) "
      + "   AND products.id.idProduct IS NOT NULL "
      + "   AND ( (:idsProducts IS NOT NULL AND  COUNT(:idsProducts)>0)"
      + ") OR productos.id.idProduct IN (:idsProducts)) ")
  List<EmpresaGrupo> obtenerEmpresasProductoServicio(@Param("idsProducts") List<Integer> 
  idsProducts,
  @Param("idsServices") List<Integer> idsServices);
```

The error jumps right where I do the Count of the @Param:

```
(:idsProducts IS NOT NULL AND  COUNT(:idsProducts)>0)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: First, you can't count the number of elements in a list in a `COUNT`. You will need to do it in the java code and pass it as argument to the method. Second, you have a `)` too much

Comment: Also, your query doesn't quite make sense, as you don't need to check if your param is null or even has more than 0 elements. These kind of checks are performed by the query itself. You can try with this query: `SELECT DISTINCT company FROM Company company LEFT JOIN company.companyProducts products INNER JOIN empresa.servicios services 
WHERE services.idService IN (:idsServices) AND products.id.idProduct IS NOT NULL and products.id.idProduct IN (:idsProducts)`

Comment: Yes, but what I want is that when it is null or size=0, it does not execute the following IN

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can read it as `idProduct IN ()`, which returns nothing, as the id is not included in nothing. Also if you worry about any null cases, you already cover them with `idProduct IS NOT NULL`